# I had over 1500 reputation yesterday. Where has it all gone?

Tags: discussion

I don't see any trace of it all disappearing... I had over 1500 now it's 1200? How'd that happen? Can anybody tell me?

I just realized that my answers here had been deleted, this is where I got a ton of rep! I'm assuming the number is the upvotes I got!

45: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2385/murder-at-the-office/2389#2389

15: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/man-commit-suicide/3061#3061

I almost got 50 upvotes on one question!

I'd like to know why these were deleted. I lost 2 privledges for this!